# Como simplificar os clicks em botões em Java para Android?

Tags: java, android

Eu estou começando a ter muitos botões na mesma Activity e por mais que são comandos simples, o código está ficando grande, e vai ficar ainda maior.

Gostaria de saber se tem um modo de simplificar diminuindo a quantidades de linhas:

Por exemplo para abrir uma activity tem gente que faz assim:

```
Intendt welcome = new Intent(Dashboard.this,WelcomeScreen.class);
startActivity(welcome);
```

Quando da para fazer numa única linha dessa forma:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,WelcomeScreen.class));
```

Agora com botões, eu estou fazendo assim:

```
--- no onCreate
    Button btn_welcome = findViewById(R.id.btn_welcome);
    btn_welcome.setOnClickListener(this);

--- no onClick
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_welcome:
        startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,WelcomeScreen.class));
    break;
}
```

Existe uma forma se simplificar tudo isso em poucas linhas?

Segue a minha classe inteira com todos os botões:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        Button btn_welcome = findViewById(R.id.btn_welcome);
        btn_welcome.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn_perfil = findViewById(R.id.btn_perfil);
        btn_perfil.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn_popup = findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);
        btn_popup.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn_intromd01 = findViewById(R.id.btn_intromd01);
        btn_intromd01.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn_spinners = findViewById(R.id.btn_spinners);
        btn_spinners.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_welcome:
                startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,WelcomeScreen.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btn_perfil:
                startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,perfil.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btn_popup:
                startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,popup.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btn_intromd01:
                startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,InstroSlidesMd01.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btn_spinners:
                startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,SpinnerLayouts.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Na minha opinião você está fazendo isso da forma mais simplificada possível.

Comment: Butterknife. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração que sua estrutura seja semelhante a essa:

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Você pode utilizar o atributo `tag` no seu elemento `Button` e depois utilizar técnicas de [Reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=reflection+%5Bjava%5D). Com isso você poderá capturar a classe, apenas passando como parâmetro, o nome dela.

Para isso basta definir o atributo *tag* com o nome da *activity* para qual o botão redirecionará o usuário.

**Exemplo XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.valdeirpsr.stackoverflow.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button #1"
        android:tag=".ProfileActivity"/> <!-- Atributo TAG -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button #2"
        android:tag=".WelcomeActivity"/> <!-- Atributo TAG -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button #2"
        android:tag=".AnotherActivity"/> <!-- Atributo TAG -->

</LinearLayout>
```

No Java, para capturar a classe através do nome, basta utilizar [Class.forName](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)). Com isso essa função de retornará o objeto `Class` que poderá ser utilizado no `Intent`.

**Exemplo no Java:**

```
package br.com.valdeirpsr.stackoverflow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ViewGroup container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn1:
            case R.id.btn2:
            case R.id.btn3:
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName(
                            getPackageName().concat(v.getTag().toString())
                    )));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigada. Não conhecia o Class.forName, vai me ajudar em muitas outras coisas também. Ja testei o seu exemplo e deu certinho. Melhorou muitoooo. obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

Para cada Button você pode atribuir o .setOnClickListener diretamente com o seu método onClick dentro de onCreate como no exemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    Button btn_welcome = findViewById(R.id.btn_welcome);
    btn_welcome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,WelcomeScreen.class));
        }
    });

    Button btn_perfil = findViewById(R.id.btn_perfil);
    btn_perfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this,perfil.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Isso diminui a distância da referência do Button com o seu metodo de onClick, deixando o código menor e mais objetivo.

Comment: Isto não deixa o código menor Diego, muito pelo contrario esse seu método deixa ele enorme. Imagine que você tem 100 botões, como ficará sua classe. Veja a resposta do Valdeir que eu coloquei como escolhida. O método dele deixa o código bem mais simplificado. Talvez seja útil para você também. bjss

Comment: Se o intuito dos Buttons for sempre abrir outras Activitys é util, mas o meu exemplo é mais versátil podendo ser referenciado não só no onCreate mas em qualquer parte de código principalmente quando se trabalha com ListView e BaseAdapter

Comment: Ahh sim Diego, no meu caso é só pra abrir outras activities mesmo, mas entendi a sua idéia sim. Obrigada pela sua resposta ^_^